# Identifying the unique values that form part of a SQL sum query

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

I have 2 queries that I would like to make work together:

1) one query sums the number of geometry points within a certain distance of another and returns results only where the count is greater 6 points;

2) one query returns the unique ID for all points within that distance (without a count and so also without a minimum number of records)

I would like to generate a single query that returns the `new_ref` from table `t2` for all (and only) the records that are summed in the first query.  (Ideally the output would be as columns in a single row, but at the moment I can’t even get the records listed in a single column against multiple rows – so this is my first aim and I could leave the pivoting bit until later).

Obviously, the system is identifying the records to count them, so I would think it should be possible to ask which records they are…

Adding in the sum statement to the second query nullifies the results.  Should I be structuring this as a sub-query and, if so, how would I do this?

Query 1 is:

```
DECLARE @radius as float = 50   
SELECT 
  t1.new_ref,
  t1.hatrisref,
  SUM
  (CASE WHEN t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius
   THEN 1 Else 0
   End) Group size'    
FROM table1 as t1,
     table1 as t2  
WHERE
  [t1].[new_ref] != [t2].[new_ref] 
GROUP BY
  [t1].[new_ref],
  [t1].[hatrisref]
HAVING
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius
    THEN 1 Else 0
  End) >5
ORDER BY
  [t1].[new_ref],
  [t1].[hatrisref]
```

query 2 is:

```
DECLARE @radius as float = 50
SELECT 
  t1.hatrisref,
  t1.new_ref,
  t2.new_ref
FROM table1 as t1,
     table1 as t2  
WHERE
  [t1].[new_ref] != [t2].[new_ref] 
  and 
  t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius
GROUP BY
  [t1].[new_ref],
  [t1].[hatrisref],
  t2.new_ref
ORDER BY
  [t1].[hatrisref],
  [t1].[new_ref],
  t2.new_ref
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited the formatting on your question.  You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more suggestions on improving the readability of your questions.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a sub-query would work:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1 as t1,  table1 as t2  
WHERE t1.new_ref != t2.new_ref 
  and t1.geolocation.STDistance(t2.Geolocation) <= @radius
and 5 < (select count(*)
         from table1 as t3
         WHERE t1.new_ref != t3.new_ref 
         and t1.geolocation.STDistance(t3.Geolocation) <= @radius
        )
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65b077/1) for a simplified example

Comment: Thanks for teh answer Darius - this hsould work but for some reason I am having trouble with the query not working with my data at the moment. I am looking into it and will post again when I have solved the problem

Comment: I was getting an error message regarding using outer references in the **GROUP BY** clause, but when I changed the **GROUP BY** to reference t3 instead of t1, this runs.  However, I am not getting any results returned when I would expect to.  I am still working on what the issue is...

Comment: Sorry cut/paste. Actually the group by is not required. Also, the WHERE clause of the nested query should also use t3.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can count and then compare that. I edited the query and also linked to a SQLFiddle that demonstrates the concept.